# How to add a new Parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2

i am still learning ruby on rails.

My first site is running but now i have this problem:

I run rails `generate scaffold staat name:string hauptstadt:string einwohner:integer sprache:string`

How is the best way for add a param like "test:string" for staat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to add another column to your database, just run:

```
rails g migration add_test_to_staats test:string
```

This will create a migration file under db/migrate

Open it up to make sure it's what you want.

The run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

I would also recommend you go through docs that explains this further, here's a link:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Comment: Yeah. Thank u! Sometimes its so easy.